# Exception within the controller is not getting executed in junit

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a controller class which is something like this:

```
@Controller
public class ExampleController
{
   @RequestMapping(value = "/samplePage")
   public ResponseEntity getSampleDetails()
   {

       SomeClass Obj = new SomeClass()
    try{
        response = Obj.getData();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response,HttpStatus.Ok)
       }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
      {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
      }
   }
}
```

I want to write a junit test case which tests for the illegal ArgumentException.Hence when someClass.getData is called I throw an Exception using Mockito.

```
 @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    public class exampleControllerTest
    {
    @Mock
    private SomeClass someClass;
    @InjectMocks
    private ExampleController exampleController;
    @Before
    public void before()
        {
         exampleControllerMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(exampleController).build();
        }

    @Test
    public void exampleControllerTest_IllegalArgumentException_throwsInternalException()
        exampleControllerMockMvc.perform(get("/samplePage")).andExpect(status().is5xxServerError);
     Mockito.doThrow(new IllegalArgumentException).when(someClass).getData()
    }
```

However when I run the code I get an error stating

Range for response status value 200 expected:SERVER_ERROR but was:SUCCESSFUL.

How do I test for the exception?

Comment: I think your parenthesis is misplaced: `Mockito.doThrow(new IllegalArgumentException).when(someClass.getData());`

Comment: `ExampleController` creates a new instance of `SomeClass` which makes it difficult to test.  @Autowired `SomeClass` and then the  mock from the test is usable, along with not need to use PowerMock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code.

1. You're not mocking constructor call `SomeClass Obj = new SomeClass();` the `SomeClass` field with `@Mock` over it does not do the job here. PowerMock is required at this place

   ```
   PowerMockito.whenNew(SomeClass.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(someClass);
   ```
2. After you should mock particular method `getData()` to throw exception, but before performing exact test request

   ```
   Mockito.doThrow(new IllegalArgumentException()).when(someClass).getData();
   ```
3. To let the PowerMock enhance the class, you need `@PrepareForTest(ExampleController.class)` on the class level
4. By convention, classes are named starting from uppercase letter, so `exampleControllerTest` -> `ExampleControllerTest`

Bringing all the things together

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ExampleController.class)
public class ExampleControllerTest
{
    private SomeClass someClass;
    private MockMvc exampleControllerMockMvc;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        someClass = Mockito.mock(SomeClass.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(SomeClass.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(someClass);
        exampleControllerMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new ExampleController())
                                                  .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void exampleControllerTest_IllegalArgumentException_throwsInternalException() {
        Mockito.doThrow(new IllegalArgumentException).when(someClass).getData();
        exampleControllerMockMvc.perform(get("/samplePage"))
                                .andExpect(status().is5xxServerError);  
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are setting up your mock after actually invoking the unit under test (your controller). You should first set your mock up and the perform the call:

```
Mockito.doThrow(new IllegalArgumentException()).when(someClass).getData();
exampleControllerMockMvc.perform(get("/samplePage")).andExpect(status().is5xxServerError);
```